# How to migrate memberships from SqlAzureMembershipProvider to Azure Active Directory

Tags: powershell, azure-sql-database, database-migration, sqlmembershipprovider, azure-active-directory

I have an existing application with a few thousand users using SqlAzureMembershipProvider for authentication.
I am interested in creating an Azure Active Directory for the application and migrating the existing membership profiles into it.
Is it technically possible to export/import the membership profiles?
The only approach I can think of is creating a PowerShell script that gets user details from the app one by one and creates a new user for each of those in the new AD.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible but there are no tools to do this.

For AD e.g. there is DirSync.

Probably easiest to use the Graph API - refer: [Azure AD Graph API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx) - samples [Microsoft Azure Active Directory Samples and Documentation](https://github.com/AzureADSamples).

As you say, you will have to cycle through the users one by one. The password is going to be a problem. You may have to give each user a dummy password to start.